# Display dynamic data with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a very simple react class, something like this

```
var Blog = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
     return (
     <div>
      <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
      <h2>{this.props.content}</h2>
     </div>
     );
   }
});
var blogTitle = "This is the title"
var blogContent = "This is the content"
React.render(
  <Blog title={blogTitle} content={blogContent} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

But I'm getting error of : JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text

I understand I can just use

```
<Blog title="this is title" content="this is content" />
```

But how can I do it so react can display dynamic data?

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `render` needs to be wrapped in an enclosing tag.
Try:

```
var Blog = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                <h2>{this.props.content}</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: I had wrapped them in a top level div but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the parameters with braces:

```
<Blog title={blogTitle} content={blogContent} />
```

Also, I don't think your `Blog` component will render. React requires that there is a single top level JSX element inside each component, so you need to wrap your contents with another element, like this:

```
var Blog = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
     return (
      <div>
          <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
          <h2>{this.props.content}</h2>
      </div>
     );
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a tool chain issue because your code is fine.